# Wie vermeide ich "dass wenn"?

Tags: conjunction

Ich habe in „Fit fürs Goethe-Zertifikat C2 – Basisgrammatik“ diesen kleinen Absatz gelesen:

> Kombinationen *dass wenn* und *weil wenn* kann man in der Umgangssprache manchmal hören.
>
> Vermeiden Sie solche Konstruktionen am besten.

Und es gibt auch zwei Beispiele:

> Du glaubst doch nicht, dass wenn du nicht mithilfst, du heute Abend weggehen kannst.
>
> Wir müssen den Termin halten, weil wenn wir das nicht schaffen, war das unser letzter Auftrag.

Meine Frage ist, wie kann man eigentlich diese Konstruktionen am besten vermeiden? Insbesondere finde ich, dass ich die Konjunktion *dass wenn* viel verwende. Wie kann ich sie anderes ausdrücken?

Comment: Eigentlich verstehe ich jetzt nicht, warum der letzen Teil des ersten Beispiels ein Nebensatz ist. Warum er ist nicht "..., kannst du heute Abend weggehen."? Hat es etwas mit die Konjunktion zu tun?

Comment: In den stilistisch unschönen Beispielsätzen fehlt außerdem jeweils ein Komma. Die Konjunktion _wenn_ ist hier nicht Teil einer Fügung, die als Einheit angesehen wird (wie z. B. „aber wenn“, „besonders wenn“ oder „ausgenommen wenn“). Daher wird der mit _wenn_ eingeleitete Zwischensatz, der hier in einen Nebensatz eingeschaltet wird, durch Komma abgetrennt: „Du glaubst doch nicht, dass, wenn du nicht mithilfst, du heute Abend weggehen kannst.“

Comment: Der zweite Beispielsatz sollte richtig lauten: »weil, weill wir das nicht schaffen, das unser letzter Auftrag **war.**«, also mit Verbentstellung (Nebensatz).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Kombinationen klingen tatsächlich ziemlich holprig, was hauptsächlich an dem daraus folgenden Satzbau liegt.

Die Beispielsätze kann man aber einfach umstellen:

> Du glaubst doch nicht, dass du heute Abend weggehen kannst, wenn du
>   nicht mithilfst.
>
> Wir müssen den Termin halten, weil das unser letzter Auftrag war,
>   wenn wir das nicht schaffen.

Comment: Vielen dank. Aber trotzdem manchmal möchte ich den "wenn" Teil erst sagen, um den zu betonen. Kann ich das machen?

Comment: @Menny Ich bin nicht ganz sicher, ob die Kombinationen grammatisch falsch sind, oder man sie so benutzen kann. Sie klingen aber ziemlich merkwürdig, so dass ich der Empfehlung, sie zu vermeiden, folgen würde. Eine zusätzliche Betonung des "Wenn"-Teils erreicht man dadurch jedenfalls nicht.

Comment: @Menny: Wenn du den "wenn" Teil zuerst sagen möchtest, um ihn zu betonen, kommst du wohl um einen kompletten Umbau des Satzes nicht herum: "Wenn du nicht mithilfst glaube nur nicht, dass du dann heute Abend weggehen kannst." oder "Wenn wir den Termin nicht halten, dann war das unser letzter Auftrag." Wobei ich den ersten Satz "Du glaubst doch nicht, dass wenn du nicht mithilfst, du heute Abend weggehen kannst." wirklich so gesagt hätte (bin Muttersprachler). Fällt mir aber auch erst auf, nachdem ich mir den Satz mehrfach vorgelesen habe... :-)

Answer (score 5):

Fixiere Dich nicht auf die Kombination mit *dass*, denn das ist nur die Spitze des Eisbergs:

Umgangssprachlich umschreibt man vieles in Nebensätzen, weil man das passende Wort nicht parat hat. Schriftlich kann (und soll) man sich mehr Zeit für die Wortwahl und -stellung nehmen. Oft findet sich ein treffendes Wort oder ein präpositionales Objekt, das den Nagel auf den Kopf trifft.

Zu Deinen Beispielen fällt mir spontan ein:

> wenn du nicht mithilfst ⇒ ohne deine Mithilfe / ohne mir zu helfen
>
> wenn wir das nicht schaffen ⇒ bei Verspätung / sonst

So vermeidet man leicht Schachtelsätze mit dicht aufeinander folgenden Konjunktionen.

Oder sollte ich besser sagen, dass wenn Sätze, weil sie zu sehr verschachtelt sind, Konjunktionen, die dabei gebraucht werden, so oft verwenden, dass weil es zu viele sind, sie keinen Satz mehr ergeben, der verständlich ist, es kein guter Stil ist?

Answer (score 3):

Wenn Du die Reihenfolge im Wesentlichen beibehalten möchtest, kannst Du einen Satz in den anderen einschieben:

> Du glaubst doch nicht, dass du, wenn (obwohl?) du nicht mithilfst, heute Abend weggehen kannst.
>
> Wir müssen den Termin halten, weil das, wenn wir das nicht schaffen, unser letzter Auftrag war.

Dabei möchte ich nicht behaupten, dass das die beste Lösung ist. Im zweiten Beispiel sind die Bezüge nicht besonders klar, und man könnte auch „wenn wir das nicht schaffen“ durch „sonst“ („andernfalls“, „ansonsten“) ersetzen.

Comment: @Loong, in diesem Fall stört es mich nicht besonders, aber im allgemeinen halte ich es nicht für gut, in anderer Texte alte gegen neue Rechtschreibung auszutauschen.

Comment: Oh, das „im wesentlichen“ war kein Tippfehler, sondern absichtlich in alter Rechtschreibung geschrieben? Verzeihung, das habe ich nicht erkannt. (Unter anderem wegen dieses Problems entstand auch diese [meta-Diskussion](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/831/9551)). In alter deutscher Rechtschreibung wäre allerdings dafür das „dass“ falsch.

Comment: @Loong, ich halte einen Pick-and-choose-Haltung gegenüber der Rechtschreibung immer noch für ok. In diesem Fall hätte ich nicht sagen können, was nun die momentane Rechtschreibung möchte, und ich musste auch nachschlagen, um mich zu vergewissern, dass die Kleinschreibung richtig war, als ich das Schreiben gelernt habe. Insofern ist es mir hier wirklich nicht wichtig. Aber nur einen Buchstaben zu verbessern, der meiner Meinung nach nicht einmal richtig falsch war, fand ich schon merkwürdig. In der Meta-Diskussion habe ich ja auch eine Mindermeinung vertreten. Aber wirklich nicht so wichtig.